# Change class name with javascript array value

Tags: javascript

I have 5 buttons, 5 class names and 1 `div`, each button when clicked, will change the class name of `div`.

I stored class name values in an array

```
function changeClass(value){
    style = new array(5)
    style[0] = "view-first"
    style[1] = "view-second"
    style[2] = "view-third"
    style[3] = "view-fourth"
    style[4] = "view-fifth"
    document.getElementById("btn").className = hoverstyle[value];
}
```

and on the button I use the `onClick` event with `changeClass(3)`

The above code is not working, I am fairly new at JavaScript and programming, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the array with a name of `style`, yet you try and apply it to the element using `hoverstyle`. Note that you can also optimise your code by using the shorthand array initialiser:

```
function changeClass(value){
    style = [ 'view-first', 'view-second', 'view-third', 'view-fourth', 'view-fifth' ];
    document.getElementById("btn").className = style[value];
}
```

Finally, `style` should be prefixed with `var` if it's only used within the `changeClass` function.

Answer (score 0):

The name of array variable is incorrect.
Change `hoverstyle` to `style`

```
document.getElementById("btn").className = style[value];
```